# Type Alias an object of a custom class

Tags: c++, c++11

Is it possible to type alias an object of a class, for example

```
using Potion = Collectable("Potion");
```

then if we have a method such as

```
void print_collectable(const Collectable& item)
{
    // print stuff from collectable i.e.
    std::cout << item.get_name() << std::endl;
}
```

we could pass Potion instead of Collectable("Potion")

```
print_collectable(Potion) vs print_collectable(Collectable("Potion"))
```

This would be expected to then print "Potion"

Obviously we could create an object called potion i.e. `Collectable potion(//...)` but I am interested to know if we can use the above to create temp objects that would be helpful when we don't need to otherwise store the object and/or to save some typing

Comment: But we **do need** an object. `print_collectable` expects one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a constant.

```
const Collectable Potion("Potion");
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
struct {
   operator Collectable() const { return Collectable("Potion"); }
} Potion;
```

where *each time* you call

```
print_collectable(Potion);
```

it would create a temporary object with `Collectable("Potion")` and pass that to `print_collectable`.